# SearchView java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception, searchview

I'm relatively new to Android, and I cannot get my project working.
I only want to display data (thanks to log.v) passed from a search field of my main activity, to another activity here called `SearchResultsActivity`. I'm following [the official android guide here](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) to do so.

However, I got a **SearchView java.lang.NullPointerException** instead for this line in my `MainActivity.java`, on logcat, when I launch the application:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.getItem(R.id.searchfield).getActionView();
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.fidbacks_search;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.getItem(R.id.searchfield).getActionView();
        // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return true;
    }

}
```

**SearchResultsActivity.java**

```
package com.example.fidbacks_search;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
         Log.v("QUERY", "fuque");

        // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
          Log.v("QUERY", query.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_results, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="test"
    android:hint="test2" >
</searchable>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fidbacks_search"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.fidbacks_search.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.fidbacks_search.SearchResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
          </intent-filter>
          <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchfield"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false" >

    </SearchView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `getActionView()` assumes you set the field `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"` for the `MenuItem` and not that you use the `SearchView` in the `Activity` layout.

Comment: Try to make the call inside the `onCreate()` instead of `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: Luksprog => I don't understand, sorry can you reformulate please?

Comment: Alfasin => When I do so, it doesn't recognize the method `getItem` for menu. I also had to import menu (Android.R).
But the android guide says to set it in the other method !

Comment: Add the property from my comment to the menu item you declared in  `R.menu.main`.

Comment: @Luksprog , I did so it still doesn't work. Between, I'm aiming to get a search widget, but not in an action bar

Comment: @Luksprog, ok I finally understand your point. So, I removed those lines from my `MainActivity.java`, I got rid of the error.
But, I still cannot pass my search variable query to my other activity, what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

use this in your menu.xml :-

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

So you need to use app namespace instead of android in the menu item tag :

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because SearchView UI is in your **activity_main.xml** while in your java file you are find the id for it using menu item object refernce by this way.

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.getItem(R.id.searchfield).getActionView();
```

So obviously you get Null pointer exception.

So for solution you have to add it to main.xml file in Menu Item.

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/search_title"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

If you don't need it on menu item then you can't add on ***onCreateOptionsMenu***. You have to use it on oncreate() method. But i think Search menu will always be on Menu Item.

```
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchfield);
    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

Comment: Thanks you, however I don't want a search widget menu item, but a "normal" search view widget (not inside the menu).
I removed the incriminated lines in my `MainActivity.java` file, I got no error anymore, but the query variable is still not passed

Comment: I placed that code under the oncreate() method, I got no error, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: I got no error I said :/ and I got no log.v output in logcat

Answer (score 1):

In Debug Check if menu.getItem(R.id.searchfield) is defined. When you call a method of inexistent element you will get nullPoint Exception.
In addition, is a best pratic always check if element exist before call your methods.

Comment: When the element doesn't exist, Eclipse would tell me so. But this isn't the case

Comment: @sidney , this is only for sintax error in this case throw a runtime error.

Comment: okay, thanks you anyways for your answer ;)
I could partially fix it with the other answer and yours too ;)